# Why the state can be undefined in redux when its type is declared?

Tags: typescript, redux, typescript-typings

I'm using [dva.js](https://dvajs.com/) (which is based on redux) to do state management in my react application. I defined a reducer as follow:

```js
import { Reducer } from 'redux';

interface StateType {
  a: any;
  b: any;
}

const setState: Reducer<StateType> = (state, { payload }) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    b: payload,
  };
};
```

And tslint would tell me that property 'a' is missing in type '{ a: any; b: any; }' but required in type 'StateType'. So I checked the d.ts file of redux and find the type declaration of a reducer:

```js
export type Reducer<S = any, A extends Action = AnyAction> = (
  state: S | undefined,
  action: A
) => S
```

It's clear that tslint considers the first parameter `state` of the reducer can be undefined, so it can't make sure that the return value type of the reducer is `StateType`. Why the state can be undefined? And if it's reasonable to be undefined, how should I change my code to eliminate the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no type for `state` argument of your reducer, so by default `state` type is `any`. You need to specify type to declare it as always defined.

```js
const setState: Reducer<StateType> = (state: StateType, { payload }) => {
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried and tslint told me type 'StateType | undefined' is not assignable to 'StateType'. I think `Reducer<StateType>` has specified the type of `state` argument as `StateType | undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [dancerphil](https://www.zhihu.com/people/dancerphil)'s advice. He provided a solution as follow:

```js
import { Reducer } from 'redux';

interface StateType {
  a: any;
  b: any;
}

const INITIAL_STATE = { a: {}, b: {} };

const setState: Reducer<StateType> = (state = INITIAL_STATE, { payload }) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    b: payload,
  };
};
```